# how to check for a condition before programmatically submitting a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a form which I want to submit only if a condition is true. But there is also a case in which I want to programmatically.

Following works when manually submitting the form:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return checkForTheCondition();"/>
```

Following works for the submitting the form programmatically but it doesn't check for the condition for submitting the form.

```
$('form').submit();
```

So I tried to do the following for programmatically checking the condition before submitting the form but when I use the following code it doesn't even submit the form which was being done by `$('form').submit();`:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    return checkForTheCondition();
});
```

`checkForTheCondition()` returns either `true` or `false`.

Is it possible to programmatically submit the form just like it works for manual form submission where it checks for a condition before submitting the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it this way:

```
if (checkForTheCondition()) {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Edit: I think I understand your problem now.

Calling `$('form').submit(function () { ... });` does NOT trigger the event. The function is not a callback! Instead it binds the function to the submit event. So when you call this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    return checkForTheCondition();
});
```

You do not trigger the event, insted you bind `return checkForTheCondition();` this is somewhat the same as `onclick="return checkForTheCondition();"` but it will be called everytime the form is submitted, and not only when the submit button is clicked.

I would do it this way:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            return checkForTheCondition();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then you can just call `$('form').submit();` and `checkForTheCondition()` will be called each time. You can read more about jQuery and submit [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).
Good luck

Edit again:

I realise the easiest solution would be this:

```
<form method="post" action="somepage" onsubmit="return checkForTheCondition();">
    <!-- Inputs -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This will make `$('form').submit();` and clicks on the submit button call `checkForTheCondition()` before submitting. Enjoy!

Comment: No he can't. There is a submit button that just submit, It doesn't pass through the `checkForTheCondition` on the way.

Comment: I believe he wants to triger the submit event from code, and want the checkForTheCondition() tested. This code will do the validation and raise the event.

Comment: @JPuge: It couldn't get cleaner than this and fortunatly it solves the problem as well and I'll accept the answer as well but I am not able to understand that why the execution doesn't get into the callback function? There is something still very surprising that I see, my breakpoints dont work the first time the code runs but when I come back again to the page the let the code run programmatically again the breakpoints work as well. The `triggerSubmit()` is being called from a `setTimeout(triggerSubmit, timeLeft)`. Does it have to go anything with the `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if it returns true/false conditionally. You can try this if you want to alert any message on failure  of condition.

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function() {
        if(!checkForTheCondition()){
           //alert message here
           return false;//This will stop the form from being submitted.
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is but here OP can alert a message if he wants to and more over it is easy to understand what actually is happening looking at the code.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: It isn't getting into the callback function. I've checked the logs. But when I click the form submit button I do get to see the the result of the `checkForTheCondition()` in `true` or `false` in the logs.

Comment: May be the `form` is not available on the page when that code is executed with attached `submit` event handler. I moved it to dom ready event now, try my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form_id').submit(function() {
  var my_value = checkForTheCondition();
  if(my_value == "some returned value"){
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("error in your submission");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend binding more closely to the `submit` event.  Forms can get submitted without clicking the submit button.

Comment: @jpea: I've tried the your code, checked the log but for some reasons it doesn't get into the callback function. but then I click the submit button manually it submits the form after checking the condition. Am not able to understand why is it not getting into the callback function?

Comment: @cheeken: I am going to try that now as the callback function don't seem to work. I barely know any javascript.

Comment: oops, edited to fix the callback function - I forgot the equals sign after the my_value declaration.

Comment: @jpea: The execution is not getting into the callback function and I am not quite able to understand why. Jpuge's answer has worked though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($( "#formID" ).submit()){
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );     
};
```